# How to get output of a Java program EXACTLY as if it was running on the terminal?

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I can redirect output to a file or other output stream with `System.setOut(...)`, but if I do:

```
System.out.print("\rTesting")
System.out.print("\rHello world!")
```

Then on the terminal I would just see "Hello world!" at the end, but if I write to a file, I get all the characters printed, and I ONLY want to get "Hello world!"

I could write a custom OutputStream that does that, but I want to handle things identically to my terminal, such as handling weird escape sequences like "\033[2K". I've tried using `cat`, `echo`, and `tee`, and redirecting to a file, but it all gives me the full sequence of characters.

Platform specific solutions are fine (though ideally it would run on any reasonable Linux distribution at least). I'm even fine with a bash command or something that will let me do this.

Comment: Do you mean you get a literal "\r" in your text file?

Comment: @RichardTingle - He means he gets `<cr>Testing<cr>Hello world!` where what he wants is `Hello world!` (no carriage return characters at all, because carriage return characters are consumed by the terminal, which repositions the cursor). AND wants handling of ANSI sequences, it appears.

Comment: The terminal just uses a protocol to decide how to display text. It sees all the characters and implements its display protocol. It's unclear what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to recreate the terminal protocol yourself, and throw away characters that would be overwritten by the terminal.

Comment: You'll have to either implement something that handles treating these characters specially in a buffer you maintain, or find an implementation that already exists (either as a Java output stream or a utility you can pipe input into and get an interpreted file as a result).

Comment: Replace `\r` with `\n` or `\r\n`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Basically yes, but as mentioned here I'd much prefer a library or command to doing it myself, because that seems very error prone/time consuming. But I need the output as a string in my Java program.

Comment: When your console shows output from different programs, do you want to have the output of your Java program only or all output written to your console (including "shutting down in 1 minute" message from root)?

Comment: @WalterA Just the output from my program. If the only way is to also get some other messages, I suppose it's alright if I can filter it out. Although at that point, it might be easier just to write my own output stream and implement at least the escape sequences I want.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Question. Why do you have these characters in the first place?

Comment: @thatotherguy Because I want to do things like display progress on the terminal (e.g., "Processing x of y"), but just updating the current line so I don't print out hundreds of lines of stuff. However, I want to capture that output for testing purposes, and I think it'd be a useful thing to know how to do anyway.

Comment: @Kytuzian This is an very common thing that thousands of tools support, including basic ones like `ls` (`ls` shows colors but `ls > file && cat file` does not). They don't do this by formatting for a tty and then stripping the formatting. Instead they format the same data differently depending on whether it goes to a file or tty. That's what you should be doing too.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that happens here is you are using CR (\r) instead of LF (\n). In your case it means that you first print line number 1 and then you jump all the way to the left but you *Don't* jump down one line and the result is that your first line disappears behind the second.

Comment: I understand that, that is the behavior I want. I want to capture that output as it appears in the terminal.